# HTC sense custom calling screen issue

Tags: android, htcsense

I have create one custom calling screen on Android.works fine on Samsung device but on HTC device it remains behind the default calling screen.I have checked the call for custom screen it show me everything ok, but why it is not showing i can not understand.
If anyone have any idea then please let me know.

If need then can post code here.

Thank you.